# Really Odd name attributes in tech test HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have been givien the html code below:
    
    
        
            First name
            Last name

```
        <td><input type="text" name="people[][surname]" value="Stelling" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="people[][firstname]" value="Chris" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="people[][surname]" value="Kamara" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="people[][firstname]" value="Alex" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="people[][surname]" value="Hammond" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="people[][firstname]" value="Jim" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="people[][surname]" value="White" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="people[][firstname]" value="Natalie" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="people[][surname]" value="Sawyer" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="OK" />
```

Do you see how the name attritbutes are defined? I have never seen that before! Looks like a 2d array but for a name in HTML? Can someone explain this to me, I really want to rewrite it, it seems like the logic and model are being mixed together!

Comment: is usually for multi records /models

Comment: That's how you would define input elements in a form with the same name. It structures your data in an array.

Comment: Just want to point out that those are [perfectly legal values for an HTML attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-attributes).

Comment: Thank you, I figured that was the case, it just feels very unnatural to me, feel this should be done in JS rather than in the HTML itself.

Answer (score 2):

As far as HTML is concerned, it is just a name. It has no special meaning. It will be encoded just like any other string.

The server side code that processes it might attribute special meaning to it. PHP in particular will convert fields with names like that into arrays of data.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you're going to get something like this:

#### PHP

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        "firstname" => "Bob",
        "surname" => "Smith"
    ),
    [1] => array(
        "firstname" => "Martha",
        "surname" => "Snow"
    )
)
```